# "You may not install to this volume because it is a Mac in target disk mode" error when installing Catalina on a mac in TDM

Tags: system-installation, macos

Hello Unix/Linux community, looking for your help.
I am running into an issue where I am trying to install Catalina 10.15.2 on a machine that has been wiped. The machine is in  target disk mode and I am using the "Install macOS Catalina" app to image this mac. When I launch the app I see all of my mounted devices including the machine that is in TDM but when I select it as the disk where I want Catalina installed I get a message that states that: "You may not install to this volume because it is a Mac in target disk mode". Is it not possible to image a mac that is in TDM? BTW I have tried imaging the disk as APFS and Mac Os Extended (Journaled). Any help/guidance is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this backward.

The computer *receiving* the installation cannot be started in TDM, the one that has the installation files must be booted in TDM.

However, this would be much, much easier if you [created a USB installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) and used that method.

Once you've downloaded the Installer Application, use the command

```
$ sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
```

Comment: the computer that is receiving the installation does not have a system on it (it has been wiped completely), when I boot the computer I cannot point it to boot off the other machine that is in TDM that has the installation, it boots to Internet Recovery automatically.

Comment: P.S. thank you for your reply.

Comment: Then you need to do Internet Recovery or make the USB install media.